# Select the voices with speechSynthesis.getVoices() javascript

Tags: javascript, voice

I have a long code, but summarizing in one line

```js
console.log(speechSynthesis.getVoices());
```

It shows in Firefox an array of voice objects, for other browsers it doesn't work and they give an empty array.

What do I have to do to have voices in other browsers?

The stackoverflow sandbox also doesn't work, it looks like [] sometimes.

Comment: It is user agent dependent so nothing you can do. Try attaching a listener on `voiceschanged`.